# Python convert bytes to str

Tags: python, string, byte

How to convert this byte value: b'Ren\xc3\xa9' to this string: 'Ren\xc3\xa9'

str(b'Ren\xc3\xa9') will return "b'Ren\xc3\xa9'" and it's not what I need

I need exactly this output in str: 'Ren\xc3\xa9'

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode it:

```
  string =  b"Ren\xc3\xa9".decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
byte_value = b'Ren/xc3/xa9'
print(byte_value.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just get the substring without the first two characters:

```
a = b'Ren\xc3\xa9'    
str(a)[2:]
```

Comment: This does not give the correct output, `str(some_bytes_object)` gives you the string representation of the *source code literal*

Comment: Try `str(a)[2:] ==  'Ren\xc3\xa9'`

Comment: it will return: "Ren\\xc3\\xa9'"
but needed 'Ren\xc3\xa9'